# I can't upload files to the server with Godot

Tags: http, godot

When I run the scene while the server is on, the server output is like this.

```
<MultiValueDict: {}> <QueryDict: {}>
[04/Oct/2019 17:04:17] "POST /upload/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13
```

This is the server output when I close the window:

```
[04/Oct/2019 17:04:28] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('B`\x82Ù')
[04/Oct/2019 17:04:28] "B`Ù" 400 -
```

Where am I doing wrong?

[Gdscript](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/RwdsmN2rvR/)

[django basic view function](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/z5JBQqtFZf/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to do a `client.close()`? Btw why dont you use the https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/classes/class_httprequest.html#class-httprequest